# DotNetNuke -- Inserting URL parameters in forms

Tags: dotnetnuke, url-parameters, dotnetnuke-6

We are migrating our website to DotNetNuke and are looking to replicate the functionality of our survey page.  Currently, on the bottom of every e-mail we send through our CRM system, there is a link to a satisfaction survey along with some parameters to pre-populate some of the fields.  So the URL looks something like like:

/survey.aspx?ticketID=1234&userName=John+Doe

I found the custom module "helferlein_Form" which seems okay for actually creating the form that the user fills in, but I don't see a way to pre-populate the fields.  DotNetNuke does let you insert tokens(ex: [Date:now], [User:username]), but I don't see a way to grab individual parameters from the URL.  Is there something I'm missing that will let me do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that module either, but I would strongly recommend using [Xmod](http://www.dnndev.com/Products/XModPro.aspx) for customized forms that allow you to easily grab url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the module you reference.

However, in my experience Dynamic Forms from Data Springs would fit the bill perfect.  It has the ability to pre-fill and even run custom SQL queries to get data.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try our [My Tokens](http://www.dnnsharp.com/dotnetnuke/modules/token-replacement/my-tokens.aspx) module.

It allows you to access the URL parameters using [Get:ticketID] or [QueryString:tickedID]. You can also build SQL tokens that use these parameters to return a list of items for example to populate a dropdown.

Also try our [Action Form](http://www.dnnsharp.com/dotnetnuke/modules/forms/action-form.aspx) module which integrates very nice with My Tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a module you like and want to use you can always write a little javascript to grab the variables out of the URL and pre-populate your form fields using javascript.